# Resolução de tela (DPI) css

Tags: css, imagem, pdf

Pretendo fazer um layout de um livro, e existem milhares de informações. Eu consigo buscá-las em uma página e adicioná-las no BD. Posteriormente iria puxá-las, fazer alguns cálculos, e retorná-las em milhares de tópicos na tela.

Nessa tela, haveria um botão de gerar um PDF em 300 dpi.

1º - Assim, gostaria de saber, se no CSS temos a possibilidade de setar a resolução do site, como é feito em imagens, em 300 pixels por polegada.

2º - É possível criar com css páginas em tamanho A5. Ao clicar em imprimir, o navegador entenda que corresponde a uma folha A5 (21 x 15 cm)

Comment: Rapaz dei uma atualizada sobre a primeira parta da sua pergunta, acho que vai te ajudar a definir qual imagem usar na impressão!

Comment: Meu caro, encontrei isso que ajuda a entender a resolução atual da tela: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/resolution , tentei usar ZOOM, mas não da certo. Eu poderia criar um (elemento) com 15 x 21 cm, mas converteria em 300 ppi, pois minha tela é de 96ppi, ou seja, ficaria enorme, e depois com zoom, eu ajustaria a minha tela para os 96ppi, mas na hora da impressão eu manteria os 300 ppi ... Mas pelo que vejo não é possível...

Comment: Acho que pode ser possível usando transform:scale() na proporção de 300/72 = 4.16, logo transform:scale(-4.16), deveria ter na tela algo de 300dpi, mas no tamanho de 72dpi. Só que eu acho isso "besteira" pq a impressora sempre imprime os textos na resolução máxima, pois o texto não deixa de ser um vetor, por isso existe tantas Icon Fonts por ai tipo a FontAwesome ou Material Icon! Fonte é vetor, e veto não precisa preocupa com resolução. A não ser que vc transforme o texto e imagem pra depois imprimir, o que não faria sentido algum...

Answer (score 1):

> 1º - Assim, gostaria de saber, se no CSS temos a possibilidade de
>   setar a resolução do site, como é feito em imagens, em 300 pixels por
>   polegada.

Sobre a primeira parte da pergunta não sei te responder com precisão, mas acho que isso tem mais a ver com a API que vai gerar o PDF do que com a tela em si. Principalmente pq estamos falando de texto e não necessariamente de imagem...

Sobre as imagens inicialmente eu pensei no `srcset`, mas para isso ele não vai servir, pois ele determina a "qualidade" da imagem dependo ta largura da tela ou da densidade de pixel da tela, não da impressão. Isso significa que ele determina a imagem no `@media screen` e não no `@media print`.

Então para ajustar a resolução da sua imagem para impressão vc tem duas opções. A primeira que é a mais fácil e acredito que é mais crossbrowser e que vai te dar menos problemas é ter 2 imagens. Uma em baixa resolução que só aparece na tela no `@media screen`, e outra `img` de alta resolução que só aparece no `@media print`

Usando a propriedade `image-resolution: 300dpi;`

**Veja que:**
 
*Fonte oficial W3C:* https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#image-resolution

> Impressoras tendem a ter resolução substancialmente maior do que monitores de computador; devido a isso, uma imagem que parece bem na tela pode parecer pixelada quando impressa. A propriedade `image-resolution` pode ser usada para incorporar uma imagem de alta resolução no documento e manter um tamanho apropriado, garantindo a exibição atraente na tela e no papel:

```
img.high-res {
    image-resolution: 300dpi;
}
```

Logo teremos algo tipo isso: **OBS:** Repare que temos duas tags de `IMG` abaixo, mas só uma delas aparece, que é a imagem com a classe `.screen`, já na impressão só a imagem classe `.print` vai aparecer, a outra some!

```css
.print {
    image-resolution: 300dpi;
}
@media only screen {
  .print {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media only print {
  .screen {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="screen" src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt="essa imagem só aparece na tela">
  <img class="print" src="https://placecage.com/200/200" alt="essa imagem só aparece na impressão">
</div>
```

**DICA:** A W3C tem em sua documentação a opção de usar valores em `DPI` para tratar imagens dentro de um `media query`, por exemplo

```
@media print and (min-resolution: 300dpi) { … }
```

Fonte: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#resolution

*Mas tenha em mente que as configurações de impressão são feitas pelo usuário, tipo se a impressão vai ser Colorida ou não, ou se vai ser em modo econômico ou não. Sendo assim é difícil saber se essa regra de resolução vai funcionar caso o usuário tenha mudado as configurações da impressora...*

---

**Já sobre isso:**

> 2º - É possível criar com css páginas em tamanho A5. Ao clicar em
>   imprimir, o navegador entenda que corresponde a uma folha A5 (21 x 15
>   cm)

Vc pode usar a `at-rule @page` e definir o tamanho da página:

```
@page {
  size: A5;
}
```

Ou

```
@page {
  size: 15cm 21cm;
}
```

Para controlar as margens vc pode fazer assim

```
@page :left {
  margin-left: 4cm;
  margin-right: 3cm;
}

@page :right {
  margin-left: 3cm;
  margin-right: 4cm;
}
```

**DICA:** Vc também pode controlar a orientação da página em vertical e horizontal *(landscape / portrair)*: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#page-size

```
@page {
    size: A5 landscape;
}
```

Essa reposta pote te interessar tb: [Diminuir tabelas para caber em uma página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/312970/diminuir-tabelas-para-caber-em-uma-p%C3%A1gina/312982#312982)

---

Documentação oficial W3C: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#at-page-rule

Artigo sobre impressão com CSS da Smash Magazine que pode te interessar: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/

Comment: Essa da impressão não conhecia, ótima dica. Encontrei algo, mas poucas informações: image-resolution: 300dpi;

Comment: @abcd Para imagens na tela, que é usado quando a tela é retina, vc pode fazer assim: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/ mas isso é para display na tela, para controlar na impressão vc teria que ter uma imagem em baixa para tela, mas no @ media print {} vc coloca uma imagem com 300dpi, tem que ver como criar essa regra e fazer um teste de impressão pra ver se da qualidade mesmo!

Comment: @abcd sobre o image-resolution vou dar uma pesquisada, se eu conseguir algo novo vou editar a resposta ;)